# Re-render one layer only in paper.js

Tags: paperjs

Is there a way to re-render a singular layer in paper.js? I know that you can just re-render the entire scene, but a canvas with thousands of shapes will affect invariably affect performance, so doing it only on the layers would be ideal.

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to do such thing unfortunately.

I suggest you use bitmap caching: save all your shapes (the layer) in a raster and draw this raster instead of the layer (just hide the layer). You would have to remove the raster and redraw everything if any of the shape change.

There could be other ways to implement this for really specific cases.

Another way is to render with webgl but it is quite complex to draw thick lines in webgl.

Answer (score 2):

You can *simulate* each layer as a different [PaperScope](http://paperjs.org/reference/paperscope/).

Since each PaperScope is tied to a specific `<canvas>` element, changes to one scope (layer in your case) will cause only it's respective canvas to be updated.

Keep in mind that if you do eventually follow this approach you'd have to manually `paperScope.activate()` your scope before working with it, since paperJS tends to do some "magic" when it comes to scope activation.

Comment: I'll have to give this a shot. Thanks for that.

Answer (score 1):

You can set the visible param on the layers that you don't want to render to false. Then draw() and set the visible back to true. It increases the performance quite a bit! ;-)

```
var tNow=(new Date()).getTime();

paper.project.layers[1].visible =false;
paper.view.draw();
paper.project.layers[1].visible = true;

console.log('Rendertime: '+((new Date()).getTime()-tNow));
```